# Time Interval column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

```
CAST(CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,ISNULL(ImS.[analystScreeningEndTime],ImS.[analystScreeningStartTime]))/15)*15,0) AS time) AS nvarchar(5)) + '-' +
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,15,CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,ISNULL(ImS.[analystScreeningEndTime],ImS.[analystScreeningStartTime]))/15)*15,0) AS time)) AS nvarchar(5)) AS Interval
```

Currently the Interval column is being sent as a string in the format of 'HH:MM - HH:MM' to the front-end but this is being sent in the UTC time zone whilst the front-end is displaying information in the local time, BST, this means the 'Interval' column is displaying a time that is 1 hour behind the local time.

Is there any way we can display data in the front-end in the correct time zone?

Comment: Use a `datetimeoffset` and then the **presentation layer** can consume that value and convert it appropriately.

Comment: @ThomA how do I use datetimeoffset? I havn't used before.

Comment: The same way you use any other data type, @CHKO . It works just `datetime2` but has the offset for the time at the end.

Comment: I am getting the error as The data types datetime2 and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: Why are you trying to *add* those 2 data types together? `2023-05-03T15:17:00 +01:00` + `'pizza'` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ThomA I didn't use together.